# Does $\mid x-y\mid>0,x\neq-y$ imply $\mid\mid x\mid-\mid y\mid\mid>0$?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$ with $x\neq -y$. Does $\mid x-y\mid>0$ imply $\mid\mid x\mid-\mid y\mid\mid> 0$ ?

**My attempt:** $\mid x-y\mid>0\implies x\neq y\implies \mid x\mid\neq\mid y\mid$ so long as $x\neq-y$, for else $\mid x\mid=\mid -y\mid=\mid y\mid$. Hence, $\mid x\mid-\mid y\mid\neq 0\implies\mid\mid x\mid-\mid y\mid\mid>0$.

Comment: Your question is equivalent on asking whether different complex numbers are different in modulus. The answer is no, as for $|1|=|i|$.

Comment: I think my answer would be correct for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, but as has been pointed out in the answers, my proof is incorrect for $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider two $x$ and $y$ on the unit circle, not opposite each other.  We have $|x|=|y|=1$, thus $||x|-|y||=0$, and yet the distance between $x$ and $y$ can take many values.  Consider for example $x=1$, $y=i$.

Comment: Thanks, so my problem lies here: $x\neq y\implies |x|\neq |y|$ since complex $x,y$ on the same "complex circle" will have the same moduli.

Answer (score 1):

These are complex numbers, so you also have, for example, $|2i|=2$.  How does that apply to your question?